# How can i move the list from left to right and right to left using javascript

Tags: javascript

I had achieved the below UI with my HTML Code but I need to implement the functionality to move the 1,2,3 numbers from left to right and right to left. Can I know how to achieve this?

```
<table>
<tr style="min-height:34px;">
<td>
<button id="leftscroll" class="mubut"onclick="moveright()">Left</button>
</td>
<td>
<ul class="nav">
<li id="list_a" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">1</li>
<li id="list_b" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">2</li>
<li id="list_c" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">3</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<button id="rightscroll" class="mubut"onclick="moveleft()">Right</button>
</td>
</table>
```

Javascript Functions which has to achieve the left to right and right to left functionality.

```
function moveleft(){
}

function moveright(){
}

function displaySelect(){
}
```

[User Interface Screenshot which was achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh6Uk.png)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. Ideally as [mre]. Use the `<>` button. Also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: please share your code, not images

Comment: You can use `order`. See more https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order

Comment: Added my html code and corresponding javascript functions.Could any one help me out as i am new to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think you need this

You need to work with [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) and [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild)

```js
function moveleft() {
 let list = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0]
 let first = list.firstElementChild
 list.removeChild(first);
 list.appendChild(first);
}

function moveright() {
 let list = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0]
 let last = list.lastElementChild
 list.removeChild(last);
 list.insertBefore(last, list.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="min-height:34px;">
    <td>
      <button id="leftscroll" class="mubut"onclick="moveright()">Left</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li id="list_a" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">1</li>
        <li id="list_b" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">2</li>
        <li id="list_c" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect()">3</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="rightscroll" class="mubut" onclick="moveleft()">Right</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve like this: list item 1234, if user press left, then becomes 2341, if press left again, becomes 2312. Press right works same.Here I use jQuery, you can conver it to DOM.

```
     function moveright(){
        //get id
        var id = $('.myli').first().attr('id');
        //get html
        var html = $('.myli').first().html();
        //remove the first li
        $('.myli').first().remove();
        //add new to the right
        $('.nav').append('<li id="' + id + '" class="myli" onclick="displaySelect();">' + html + '</li>');
    }
```

For right, can just use $('.myli').last() and $('.nav').prepend(htmlContent).